# Brazilian citizen with Romanian working visa: Can I travel to Canada without a visa?

Tags: visas, canada, romania, brazilian-citizens

I am from Brazil and I have a working visa in Romania.

Can I travel to Canada without a travel visa and use my passport and working visa to enter Canada for a short visit (7 days holiday) or do I have still to apply for a visitor visa?

FYI I also do have a business in Romania... does this change anything?

Comment: *blink* why on earth would Canada care about a Working Visa to Romania?

Answer (score 2):

**No**, you need to apply for a travel visa to Canada. Your status in Romania is irrelevant in this case, only your citizenship matters (according to [CIC](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/visas.asp)). There's a visa office in [Bucharest](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/information/times/temp/visitors.asp#europe) and their average processing time is 8 days for a completed application but you can also apply [online](http://www.cic.gc.ca/ctc-vac/getting-started.asp)

[image]